# Play Framework and WS library - how to check progress?

Tags: web-services, api, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.1 and it's WS library to upload a file. This file can be huge and I'd like to know how far into the upload I am. I can't find anything to make it possible (like progress callbacks, anything) but maybe there's some trick to that?